# MySQL Error "Unknown column in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have the following SQL command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aiContract 
    ( IN pStudent VARCHAR(63), IN pStartDate BIGINT, IN pEndDate BIGINT, 
        IN pAdvisor VARCHAR(255), IN pResearchGroup INTEGER, IN pProject VARCHAR(255), 
        IN pWage DOUBLE, IN pHours INTEGER, IN pLastConfirmation BIGINT, OUT newId INT )
    begin 
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), -1) + 1 INTO newId FROM contract; 
        INSERT INTO contract 
            VALUES(newId, pStudent, pStartDate, pEndDate, pAdvisor, pResearchGroup, pProject, pWage, pHours, pLastConfirmation); 
    end;
```

and once it totally worked fine but now i get the following errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'newId' in 'field list'

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1
```

I execute this command using JDBC. Here is the java code:

```
List<String> sqls6 = new LinkedList<>();
                sqls6.add("delimiter //");
                sqls6.add("CREATE PROCEDURE aiContract "
                        + "( IN pStudent VARCHAR(63), IN pStartDate BIGINT, IN pEndDate BIGINT, "
                        + "IN pAdvisor VARCHAR(255), IN pResearchGroup INTEGER, IN pProject VARCHAR(255), "
                        + "IN pWage DOUBLE, IN pHours INTEGER, IN pLastConfirmation BIGINT, OUT newId INT ) "
                        + "begin SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), -1) + 1 INTO newId "
                        + "FROM contract; INSERT INTO contract VALUES(newId, pStudent, pStartDate, pEndDate, "
                        + "pAdvisor, pResearchGroup, pProject, pWage, pHours, pLastConfirmation); end//");
                sqls6.add("delimiter ;");
                sqls6.add("ALTER TABLE contract CHANGE ID ID INTEGER;");

                Statement stmt6 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < sqls6.size(); i++) {

                    try {
                        stmt6 = getStatement();
                        stmt6.execute(sqls6.get(i));
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        // closing statement [...]
                    }
                }
```

Why? :(

Edit: 
I did not change anything (at least i could not say what), but it suddenly worked. Can't tell what the problem was here.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. Have done so now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating in mysql then you may have forgotten to set your delimiters

```
drop procedure if exists aicontract;
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE aiContract 
    ( IN pStudent VARCHAR(63), IN pStartDate BIGINT, IN pEndDate BIGINT, 
        IN pAdvisor VARCHAR(255), IN pResearchGroup INTEGER, IN pProject VARCHAR(255), 
        IN pWage DOUBLE, IN pHours INTEGER, IN pLastConfirmation BIGINT, OUT newId INT )
    begin 
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), -1) + 1 INTO newId FROM contract; 
        INSERT INTO contract 
            VALUES(newId, pStudent, pStartDate, pEndDate, pAdvisor, pResearchGroup, pProject, pWage, pHours, pLastConfirmation); 
    end //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: This works for me in mysql, but not when I execute that from Java (forgot to mention that in the question initially